# Need to apply following patch of total amount including tax in magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2

I am facing issue in cart price rule. I have set the total amount condition as >= 25, but it gets applied for total in cart excl tax & not incl tax.

While debugging I came across following link

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12396

I am using magento ver 2.2.5 (Enterprise)

How can I apply following patch in my magento & then set condition?

The above issue is in new release of 2.2.9 but how can I apply it in my magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Put your patch file at root folder and run this command, I have apply patch successfully using this command.

> Ex. patch -p1 < MDVA-14172_EE_2.2.6_COMPOSER_v1.patch
>
> patch -p1 < your patch file name

Comment: Okay, But can you once chk the above mentioned link of mine & help me find patch